# Why my model box doesn't have the dimension of the line height with padding=0 and marging =0?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working with CSS/HTML. I'm using Bootstrap 4.
In a line of menu, I want the box the same size as the font-size. I put margin and padding to 0.

```css
.menu-ppal {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-ppal li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-ppal-text a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #d6dbdf;
  color: #111a21;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-ppal">
  <ul class="nav flex-column flex-md-row ">
    <li class="nav-item menu-ppal-text">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Actus</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If I read the developer tools, the font-size is 16px, the padding and margin are 0, but the model box is 50.4333×21

I have the same behavior in different locations...

Comment: You really won't be able to do what I think you are trying to do. There is space above/below character glyphs **built into** fonts to stop characters overlapping on different lines.

Comment: Did you use `<ul class="nav flex-column flex-md-row menu-ppal">`?

Comment: try setting line-height to 1 or 0 like `line-height: 1;`

Comment: The CSS code provided doesn't apply to the HTML provided. I've added them to a Stack Snippet so that everyone can see what happens.

Comment: @Paulie_D : I think I'm able. The website I'm trying to reproduce do exactly that: https://odpf.org/c-est-quoi.html

Comment: @SatoTakeru Yes, i have used this, and my menu, instead of being in line went in block...

Comment: @Rojo I've tried, and that doesn't change anything...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you. I don't know how to do that.  You can see the color #d6dbdf is 2.5 px above and below the text...

Comment: I think you need to edit the HTML so that the class `menu-ppal` is on the `ul`, as @SatoTakeru mentions in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495889/why-my-model-box-doesnt-have-the-dimension-of-the-line-height-with-padding-0-an?noredirect=1#comment122835370_69495889)

Comment: @HereticMonkey   in fact, this html code is surrouneded by a <nav class="menu-ppal">...</nav>

Comment: I've added that to the snippet. Now, when we click "Run code snippet", the CSS will apply, and we can see what you are talking about. This is described as a [mre] and talked about in [ask], a good place to get tips on asking better questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Many thanks...

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. Well, the idea is good, but, with that the "menu" is no more in line, but in block. And, with that, with 5 menu-items, the 5 menu-item are in the same place...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to dynamically do this. I just added `position: absolute` and set a smaller `height`.

```css
.menu-ppal {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 16px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-ppal li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-ppal-text a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #d6dbdf;
  color: #111a21;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-ppal">
  <ul class="nav flex-column flex-md-row ">
    <li class="nav-item menu-ppal-text">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Actus</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You'll notice that there is still one pixel at the top where there is still some background

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer  !
At the beginning of my css file, I put a call to Google api fonts. I copied this call from the site I'm trying to copy :

> @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700);

It' quite &ncient (seven years), and, with this ancient call, the effect is exactly what I'm hoping...
And, workin with my browser's Developper tools, I read that's ancient and I use the new from Google :

> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

And, with that one, I have the ugly effect !